# SQL Procedure behavior while having multiple if statements

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, stored-procedures

I have stored procedure like this,

```
Create Procedure [dbo].[Get_Data](
@Id as Varchar(20),
@Type as Varchar(10)
)
As
Begin
  IF(@Type = 'skill')
  Begin 
   .....
   select * ....
  END

  IF(@Type = 'agent')
  Begin 
   .....
   select * ....
  END

  IF(@Type = 'skillProfile') 
  Begin 
    Print 'abc'
    select * ....
   .....
  END
END
```

**Note**: there is no syntax or any other error inside any of the if loops as every `select` query inside each loops are tested successfully.

So now, When i try to execute procedure using command as below,

```
EXEC  [Get_Data] '1391520','skillProfile'
```

the statement `print` is not printed also dint get any rows in return, instead i get message `Commands completed successfully.`

I tried changing last(i.e. here third) if loop statement i.e. from `IF(@Type = 'skillProfile')` to `IF(@Type = 'profile')` and tried executing like  `EXEC  [Get_Data] '1391520','profile'` which worked all fine!

Got confused with this and tried changing first if loop and last(third) if loop like this,   `IF(@Type = 'skill')` to  `IF(@Type = 'xyz')` and `IF(@Type = 'skillProfile')` to `IF(@Type = 'xyzProfile')` and tried executing like  `EXEC  [Get_Data] '1391520','xyzProfile'` which also worked all fine.

Now i am totally confused why it doesn't work when i use `skill` and `skillProfile`.

Answer (score 3):

You defined your parameter as Varchar(10), which means it cannot hold more than 10 characters. If you try to assign it a longer value, it gets truncated with no warning. So you are trying to execute your procedure with `@Type='skillProfi'`. The solution is to increase the size of your parameter, say `varchar(100)`.

Comment: oh shit! yes you are right, i dint notice that. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Use Try catch block you will let know where error is

```
Create Procedure [dbo].[Get_Data](
@Id as Varchar(20),
@Type as Varchar(10)
)
As
BEGIN TRY
    SET NOCOUNT ON
  IF(@Type = 'skill')
  Begin 
   .....
   select * ....
  END

  IF(@Type = 'agent')
  Begin 
   .....
   select * ....
  END

  IF(@Type = 'skillProfile') 
  Begin 
    Print 'abc'
    select * ....
   .....
 END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
     ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity
     ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState
     ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure
     ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine
     ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
END CATCH
```